# Can't delete a record from map

Tags: c++

```
string* Foooood::topFiveFoo(){    
    std::map<std::string, unsigned long> volumes;
    typedef std::map<std::string, unsigned long>::iterator it_type;

    for(i=0;i<nTransactions;i++){
        volumes[tDeque.at(i).fooSymbol] += tDeque.at(i).fooShares;
    }

    string top;
    string result[5];
    int check = 0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(it_type iterator = volumes.begin(); iterator != volumes.end(); iterator++) {
            if(iterator->second > check){
                top = iterator->first;
                check = iterator->second;
            }

            result[i] = top;
            volumes.erase(top);
        }
    }
    return new string[5];
}
```

I have only learned about maps less than 12 hours ago, so I am still very confused.
I keep getting the error: "Debug Assertion Failed!" ..... "Expression:map/set iterator not incrementable"

In my head if I find the top value, store it in the array and then delete it from the map, I will be able to repeat this and generate a top 5 list!?? But I can't delete the top value and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Where do you set `nTransactions`?

Comment: You're missing a close bracket somewhere after the second for loop... where should it go?

Comment: `nTransactions` are stored outside of the class.

Comment: @Will: OK, that's pretty clear, but what is the statement that sets it? You should provide some context. You may be accessing out-of-bounds elements of the queue

Comment: @Xymostech: sorry, fixed now. But that wasn't the problem.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I should clarify that once I remove the `volumes.erase(top);` I get no errors and it works flawlessly until then. `nTransactions` can be substituted by 20 as it ranges anywhere from 20 to 100000. Again, you can ignore that part as the map only stores 20 records as there are only 20 `tDeque.at(i).fooSymbol` variations. Hope this clarifies it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`std::map::erase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/erase/)

> **Iterator validity**
>   Iterators, pointers and references referring to elements removed by the function are invalidated.
>   All other iterators, pointers and references keep their validity.

So, if your iterator points to the deleted element, it is invalid after `erase` and you are not allowed to increment it.

Another point is your return value. If you want to return the `result` array, you must copy it first or allocate it on the heap right away. Right now, you return an empty `std::string` array.

```
std::string *result = new std::string[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(it_type iterator = volumes.begin(); iterator != volumes.end(); iterator++) {
        if(iterator->second > check){
            top = iterator->first;
            check = iterator->second;
        }
    }

    result[i] = top;
    volumes.erase(top);
}

return result;
```

Comment: My train of thought was that if I delete it outside of the iterator loop, it would just re-count the map records?

Comment: @Will `volumes.erase(top);` is inside your iterator for loop.

Comment: My code is such a mess that I just realised you're absolutely right! Problem is that my `volumes.erase(top);` was within my for loop! Thank You! :)

Comment: @Will Please see answer regarding your return value.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Error: argument list for class template "std::vector" is missing" ?

Comment: @Will Sorry, I shouldn't give advice at this time, fixed. You must also modify the return type of your method to `std::vector<std::string>`, of course. If this is too much hassle, just ignore me. :-)

Comment: I spent all day brain dead staring at this. No progression can be too much hassle! I have declared result as `std::vector<std::string> result;` and modified the rest of the code. But when I `return result;` I get: _Error: no suitable conversion function from "std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>"to "std::string *" exists_ :(

Comment: @Will You must modify the return type of `topFiveFoo()` as well. Please see modified answer. This will also affect *all of the callers* of `topFiveFoo()`. That's why I said, "too much hassle" ;-)

Comment: I see now. Problem is that the supplied part of the code contains so many pointers that I am unable to modify the return types. You mentioned: _If you want to return the result array, you must copy it first_ , where do i copy it? Sorry for being annoying. I am genuinely lost.

Comment: Since you can't change the return type then `string* result = new string[5];` and `return result;` is what you need I think. It's bad coding, but if you have to do it that way then so be it.

Comment: @Will Alright, next try. You don't need to copy it, if you allocate the result on the heap. Don't forget to `delete[]` it when you don't need it anymore, otherwise you will have memory leaks. See modified answer.

Comment: Yeah `string* result = new string[5];` works perfectly! Thank you so much Olaf and john! This is the happiest I've been in a while haha :)